# What is the use of creating Constant (let) empty Array object?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In the Swift PDF file released by Apple i came thorough this code

To create an empty array or dictionary, use the initializer syntax.

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
```

Here what is the use of creating a let (constant) object with empty array, where we cannot insert any values into it in next line ??!!

Comment: I'd personally raise this as a minor bug in the documentation. It would make a lot more sense if those examples used variables rather than constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much use, but the value can be copied:

```
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
var otherDictionary = emptyDictionary
otherDictionary["a"] = 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

while teaching objective- c they start teaching like

```
NSArray *arrayObj = [[NSArray alloc] init]
```

if we declare like this we cannot add objects after initialisation
similarly they are teaching us how to initialise an array or dictionary objects

one more difference is if we allocate an empty array then we can assign another array with this.

let will not allow you to assign another array to it also

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let/var filledArray = ["stack", "overflow"]

emptyArray = filledArray  //  will give you an error
```

Answer (score 0):

The property declaration sets them to a default, but you could actually change the value to something else in init. This would only be the case for class properties, not inline properties though.

Here's an example in a class scope where a let property can have a default but be changed:

```
class Whatever {

    let testArray = [Int]()

    init() {
        testArray = [0,1,2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give any example please ?